# Process for deploying the Safe web app on a custom EVM-compatible network

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, gnosis-safe

My objective is to deploy the Safe app on a custom EVM-compatible network, using the [safe-infrastructure](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure) repository. I do not intend for the custom network to be listed alongside officially supported networks such as Polygon, Arbitrum, Volta, and Goerli.

Despite the nice documentation from the Gnosis Safe team, I am still not sure about the whole process and I need your help.

Based on my understanding of [the official document](https://help.safe.global/en/articles/6227806-supported-networks), the process is described as follows.

##### [A]

[image]

However, I have seen several issues and PRs related to adding new networks that go beyond the process mentioned above (e.g. [this](https://github.com/safe-global/safe-infrastructure/issues/64#issuecomment-1442760897)), and I am suddenly confused.

##### [B]

[image]

#### Questions:

1. Could you please guide me in fixing my misunderstandings? Which is more correct between A and B?
2. How long does the process take in general? All PRs are generally merged by contributors, and there are some serial processes, so I can't figure out the time.

#### Related repositories

- https://github.com/safe-global/safe-singleton-factory
- https://github.com/safe-global/safe-contracts
- https://github.com/safe-global/safe-deployments/
- https://github.com/safe-global/web-core/
- https://github.com/safe-global/safe-core-sdk/
- https://github.com/safe-global/safe-config-service/
- https://github.com/safe-global/safe-transaction-service/
- https://github.com/safe-global/safe-eth-py/

Answer (score 0):

I contacted the Safe team and was informed that the answer is more similar to option A than option B.

Answer (score 0):

I think that option B is correct. I am trying to use safe app on custom network that unsupported network. By my research, option B is correct.